# Android Studio how do I know if an Image has been updated from Firebase?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-storage

So I set an imageView with an image from Firebase storage. The image is downloaded into app cache so that it is available offline.
But if the image was changed and the image has the same name, how do i do that with code?

(The images show up on the phone, but when i change one in firebase storage it stays the same on the phone)

Here is what I have

```
    ImageView i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ImageView i2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ArrayList<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<>(2);
    images.add(i1);
    images.add(i2);
    String str = "images.jpg";
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            str = str.substring(0,6) + i + ".jpg";
            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(str);
            Glide.with(this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into(images.get(i));
        }
```

how do i know if the image was changed but it has the same name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to write a [storage trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) that executes whenever a file changes in your storage bucket.  You could then have that send a notification to your app using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: I have researched Cloud Functions and it is what I need. But i have no idea what to do with their code. I type it in and I get compile errors. If someone could give me an example that would be awesome.